# PHP array limit?

Tags: php

friends i am new in php. I am playing with array. So i am unable to solve one login using array. In this program i want to show array limit. I have number of data it's come form Database. But i want to show limit data like ( 10 posts only ). I know the MYSQL query to show limit data. But i am trying with array. So please help to solve this logic thanks.

here is the code.

```
$reverse = array_reverse($showpost, true);

foreach ($reverse as $key=>$postvalue) {
    $latestpost = explode(',', $postvalue['postcategory']);

    if (in_array("3", $latestpost)) {
        // result here...

    }

}
```

I have save the category this format (1,2,3,4,5,6). That's why I have used explode() function. 
My DataBase fields name are ( post_id, postname, postcategory, postdisc,).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I've understood the problem correctly but I think it maybe related to [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)

```
$input = array("a", "b", "c", "d", "e");
$output = array_slice($input, 0, 3);   // returns "a", "b", and "c"
```

Comment: but how to show data using this function. because $output['postname'] is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_chunk()` function

CODE:

```
<?php
$reverse = array_reverse($showpost, true);

foreach($reverse as $key=>$postvalue){
    $latestpost = explode(',', $postvalue['postcategory']);
    $chunks = array_chunk($latestpost, 3);
    print_r($chunks);
}
?>
```

Comment: but how to display data my using $chunks['postnane'] this method not working.

Comment: $chunks is array in 3 values pairs just use foreach loop or with index like if you want to print first pair then use $chunks[0]  for next array just increase index 1,  2 like this

Answer (score 0):

If you're only wanting to show 10 rows, and `result here...` is where each post is show, then something like this may work:

```
$postsShown = 0;
$reverse = array_reverse($showpost, true);

foreach ($reverse as $key => $postvalue) {

    if ($postsShown >= 10) {
        break;
    }

    $latestpost = explode(',', $postvalue['postcategory']);

    if (in_array("3", $latestpost)) {

        // result here...

       $postsShown++;
   }
}
```

All this does is count how many posts are shown using the `$postsShown` variable, and increments it when a new post is shown. When this variable reaches 10 (IE, 10 posts are shown), the loop will be terminated using the `break` command.

Comment: sorry your logic is not working...

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use a session variable to save few attempts the user used to log, and you validate it in the server.

with this code you can create a session variable:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name_of_my_variable'] = 'value of my session variable';
```

and for example each time the user tries to log you can increase the value of your counter in the session variable:

the first time you needs create the session variable:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['log_counter'] = 1;
```

and the next attempts you increment the counter like this:

```
session_start();
$log_counter = $_SESSION['log_counter'];
$log_counter++;
$_SESSION['log_counter'] = $log_counter;
```

check if the user already reached the limit:

```
session_start();
if ($_SESSION['log_counter'] == 10)
{
    echo "Limit reached";
}
```

**This is the final code**:

```
// init session variables
session_start();

// Check if exist the session variable
if (isset($_SESSION['log_counter']))
{
    // Enter here if the session variable exist

    // check if the log_counter is equals to the limit
    if ($_SESSION['log_counter'] == 10)
    {
        echo "Limit reached";
    }else
    {
       // increase the counter
       $log_counter = $_SESSION['log_counter'];
       // this increate 1 more to the log_counter session variable
       $log_counter++;
       // here we save the new log_counter value
       $_SESSION['log_counter'] = $log_counter;
    }
}else
{
    // Enter here if not exist the session variable

    // this create the log_counter session variable
    $_SESSION['log_counter'] = 1;
}
```